# How does timeout variable in debounce work?

Tags: javascript

when on click is called multiple times

```
jQuery("#elementid").click( _.debounce( somefunction , 1000 ) );
```

How does timeout is shared between multiple clicks when _.debounce is called ?

```
_.debounce = function(func, wait, immediate) {
    var result;
    var timeout = null;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) result = func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) result = func.apply(context, args);
        return result;
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
_.debounce = function(func, wait, immediate) {
    var result;
    var timeout = null;
    return function() { /*returned function
*/ 
} }
```

Note where timeout and result variables are declared,outside the returned function.The returned function remembers the context in which it was defined,that's called a closure.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)

So everytime the returned function calls timeout it will be the timeout declared in the closure.

Comment: Arent those variable gets declared again hence new variables when bounce gets called again??

Comment: what is called again and again is the returned function,not debounce itself,debounce returns a function.When you call debounce it executes a function once,this function returns a function(an event handler in your case).You are not executing debounce multiple times.

Comment: @mpm Your answer is so wrong. Of course debounce is called multiple times.  If click happens only once, why would you need to debounce?  You need to debounce because the button is getting clicked multiple times.  Each time the debounce is called, the timer is cleared and started again.  Only when there is a quite period of 'delay' has passed, the timer will fire and the callback function will be called  ONLY ONCE (not multiple times).

Comment: debounce is not called multiple times, what is called multiple times is the function returned by debounce.debounce itself is called once.My point is easily proven by using sinon.js

Comment: and by the way,the returned function IS called again and again, what is called at specific intervals IS the event handler for click.but the returned function IS called on each click. So I wonder where you think i'm wrong,i'm not.I ported this lib in multiple languages I know it pretty  good.

Comment: Got it, thank you mpm, i read a bunch of tutorial yesterday and your explanation is very helpful !